# Animation Nodes : how can I switch between different setups?

Tags: animation-nodes

Is it possible to work on several animation nodes NodeTrees and to switch between them / select the active one ?

I see AN generates a "Animation Nodes Object Container" object.
Is the nodetree attached to it ? And how ?

Thanks for your lights.

G

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Animation Nodes Object Container

The *Animation Nodes Object Container* is created as a helper object for the *Object Instancer* node, in other words, it is only created when the *Object Instancer* node is used. Notice that it doesn't get removed when the *Object Instancer* node is removed and it is a single object even if you have multiple *Object Instancer* nodes.

#### Node Trees

If multiple Node Trees are presents, all of them executes based on the defined *Auto Execution* settings. So if both have *Always* option enabled, both will execute simultaneously. So there really isn't an "Active Node Tree". Subprograms are shared across Node Trees, so you can call a subprogram defined in one node tree in another.

Animation Nodes provide a fast way to disable/enable *Auto Execution* for the available node trees, this is done through the *Overview Panel*:

[image: Overview]

Comment: Thanks for those informations. And then, is it possible to have multiple node trees and to execulte only one of them (in a simple way) ? Thanks

Comment: @gordie Sure, just disable Auto Execution on the ones you don't want to execute. A fast and simple way to do this is by using the *Overview* panel in the *T* menu, you will see a dot beside each node tree, pressing that disable/enable Auto execution.

Comment: Ok Omar, I didn't get that !  If you edit your answer to add this, I'll validate it.  Thanks !

Comment: @gordie Edited the answer.